# Laravel eloquent model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, entrust, eloquent-relationship

My app builds on

```
Laravel: 5.6.35
PHP 7.2.4
Entrust: 1.9
```

My Role model

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

And my User model is

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    } 
}
```

And now you can notice in Tinker

```
D:\work\www\myapp>php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.7 (PHP 7.2.4 â€” cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\models\Role::find(1)->users()->get()
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.role_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`role_id` = 1 and `users`.`role_id` is not null)'
>>> App\User::find(1)->role()->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2937
     all: [],
   }
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles()->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2941
     all: [
       App\models\Role {#2930
         id: 1,
         name: "super-admin",
         display_name: "Super Admin",
         description: "This will be one permission, that can not be assigned or modified.",
         created_at: "2018-09-07 12:11:35",
         updated_at: "2018-09-07 12:11:35",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2927
           user_id: 1,
           role_id: 1,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

I am getting result for `App\User::find(1)->roles()`, but my User model has function `role()`, and empty collection for `App\User::find(1)->role()` and error for `App\models\Role::find(1)->users()`

so please give some idea, how to solve this issue?

Comment: if roles is giving result, why don't you simply change the role to roles in User Model.

Comment: Do you have a field "role_id" in your users table?

Comment: @CarlosSalazar no, but their is another table that maintains role_user relationship.

Comment: "my role model"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339620/5321614).if you have properly defined relations through hasMany and belongsTo in your models, but haven't provided foreign key in the table of the model who belongsTo other table, your relations won't work. In documentation too, it suggests to use foreign_key to use [One-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship.

Entrust database design is based on many-to-many relationship. So that user can have multiple roles.Purly as described in Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

The way you have defined your relationships, you have to explicitly ask to retrieve that relation:

```
App\User::with('Roles')->find(1)->roles()
```

In the documentation, the relationship between user and role is like this:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to ask for the relationship

Comment: So, what is the point of defining a method in `User` model and defining relation, that `Role` and `User` has `One-To-Many` relationship?, The `role()` should return the role associated with specified user, right?

Comment: I want a hasMany relationship not a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The probles is either in the way your relationship is created or in your table, the error says

```
 Unknown column 'users.role_id' in 'where clause'
```

that means that in your users table is missing the column `role_id`, when you make a relationship like

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

The hasMany will try to find the`tablename_id` in the model you're passing, if you want to get them by a third table you could use `belongsToMany` on your `permission` Model or using [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: No, my model using One-to-May relationship. Check my answer for explanation.